# invalid parameter 1 specified for datadiff

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms, datediff, sql-agent-job

I want to update field everyday automatically in database about duration. the formula is (due date - date now). I want to use sql server agent. But when I test the job its failed.

```
USE FacilityMonitoring
GO

UPDATE [dbo].[klaim]
   SET selisihint = DATEDIFF ("dd", GETDATE(), durasi_end)
GO
```

Query in SQL Server agent:

[image: query in sql server agent]

Error:

[image: error showing like this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First argument of [`datediff()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms189794(v=sql.110).aspx) is the datepart. It's not a string though, so replacing `"dd"` with `dd` should do the job:

```
USE FacilityMonitoring
GO

UPDATE [dbo].[klaim]
   SET selisihint = DATEDIFF (dd, GETDATE(), durasi_end)
GO
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks a lot. It works. It because the argument string. @kamil-g

Comment: For anyone else in a similar position, this solved it for me when migration from an Access DB to MS SQL Server, where the string syntax "dd" was working in Access.

Answer (score 1):

You quotes are redundant (read: wrong). Remove them, and you should be OK:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[klaim]
   SET selisihint = DATEDIFF (dd, GETDATE(), durasi_end)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use database name

```
UPDATE [schema_name].[Table_name]
   SET column_name= DATEDIFF (dd, GETDATE(), durasi_end)
```